# How to run this html combobox sample?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi everyone I've been looking for a simple example on how to make an html select appear like a combobox. I found a sample code snippet from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180890/drop-down-with-free-input). Its actually an answer to a question similar to mine. Its answered by `Samich`. It has a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rYVJT/2/). I copied the code from jsfiddle and tweaked it a little bit to make it run on my machine but I can't make it run.

Here is the code (Most of the codes are written by Samich):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #dropdown { position:absolute; width:200px; display:none; }
            #dropdown li:hover { background:#ccc; cursor:pointer; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.4min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 
            $('#btn').click(function() {
                var pos = $('#txt').offset();
                pos.top += $('#txt').width();
                $('#dropdown').fadeIn(100);
                return false;
            });

            $('#dropdown li').click(function() {
                $('#txt').val($(this).text());
                $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="txt" /><a href="#" id="btn">V</a>
        <ul id="dropdown">
            <li>Value 1</li>
            <li>Value 2</li>
            <li>Value 3</li>
            <li>Value 4</li>
            <li>Value 5</li>
            <li>Value 6</li>
            <li>Value 7</li>
            <li>Value 8</li>
            <li>Value 9</li>
            <li>Value 10</li>
            <li>Value 11</li>
            <li>Value 12</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am very new to javascript and jquery so please bear with me guys. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is the src of your jQuery javascript file correct? maybe it should be `jquery.1.6.4.min.js` ?

Comment: @TimBJames Its working now. I just forgot the $(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var pos = $('#txt').offset();
    pos.top += $('#txt').width();

    $('#dropdown').fadeIn(100);

    return false;
  });

  $('#dropdown li').click(function() {
    $('#txt').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost! you need to make sure the script that attaches events to the elements runs *after* the elements have been created by the browser, to do this just use the ready() function;

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            var pos = $('#txt').offset();
            pos.top += $('#txt').width();
            $('#dropdown').fadeIn(100);
            return false;
        });

        $('#dropdown li').click(function() {
            $('#txt').val($(this).text());
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You have very similar answer with Krister but he answered first. Thanks so much anyway for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [comboBox which is part of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)?

Comment: I tried but I am very confused. I dont know what files I need and where to begin with.

Answer (score -2):

If you use `<a href="#" id="btn">V</a>`  then `do $('btn')` not `$('#btn')`...

Comment: I changed $('#btn').click(function()  to $('btn').click(function() but still not working.

Comment: @KristerAndersson +1 because the reason is I wasn't able to place the $(document).ready

Comment: `$('#btn')` would select the element with the id `btn`. `$('btn')` would select any element `<btn>`